# javax.mail: how to log its telnet session to SMTP servers?

Tags: java, email, logging, jakarta-mail, slf4j

How can I get JavaMail to log its full telnet session to slf4j? I have a slf4j configured and working for all the other packages I want. When I add `<logger name="javax.mail" level="TRACE"/>` to the config, no output. Is the level called FINE for javax.mail? Is this detail even possible to output?

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail uses java.util.logging to log messages.  I don't know how slf4j connects to that.  The package javadocs for the various JavaMail packages describe what logger names and levels they use.  See the bottom of the [com.sun.mail.smtp package javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) for example.